# POST data to the mojang api with node.js using request module

Tags: node.js, api, http, request, node-modules

I am using node.js for a discord bot and I want to use the [Request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to post a name to the mojang api and get a uuid back.
here is my code:

```
var uuid = request.post({
        url:     'https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft',
        name:    `${username}`
    }, function(error, response, body){
        console.log(body);
        return response.id;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @willymarj said, the data is returned in the body, not the response object. You will also want to parse the JSON response into a javascript object.

```js
var uuid = request.post({
        url:     'https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft',
         name:    `${username}`
    }, function(error, response, body){
        return JSON.parse(body.id);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

response from body not response.

```
var uuid = request.post({
        url:     'https://api.mojang.com/profiles/minecraft',
         name:    `${username}`
    }, function(error, response, body){
        return body.id;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! i will try this.

Comment: It now returns: `[object Object]`